# DefaultMonetaryConversionsSingletonSpi could not be instantiated

Tags: java, currency, java-money

I am using Java money API in Eclipse to get convert USD to EUR but I am getting following error

Provider org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.DefaultMonetaryConversionsSingletonSpi could not be instantiated

Below is the code from my POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
  <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Below is the full error

```
[Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.money.spi.MonetaryConversionsSingletonSpi: Provider org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.DefaultMonetaryConversionsSingletonSpi could not be instantiated] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.javamoney.moneta.spi.MonetaryConfig.getString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional;
```

Comment: Can you add full error?

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: No, please at it in description and apply code format for easily reading.

Comment: Updated error in description with code format.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: It seem the error was caused the mismatch of dependency library. Please add full pom.xml or You can add dependency tree by using mvn dependency:tree .

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use method (or some library that you youse)

```
Optional org.javamoney.moneta.spi.MonetaryConfig.getString(String)
```

but there is no such method. There is only

```
Map<String,String> org.javamoney.moneta.spi.MonetaryConfig.getString()
```

[V1,0](https://javadoc.io/static/org.javamoney/moneta-bp/1.0/org/javamoney/moneta/spi/MonetaryConfig.html), [V1.4](https://javadoc.io/static/org.javamoney/moneta-bp/1.4/org/javamoney/moneta/spi/MonetaryConfig.html) and [latest](https://javadoc.io/static/org.javamoney/moneta-bp/1.4.1/org/javamoney/moneta/spi/MonetaryConfig.html)

Please check your code against this method, if not help, then try to use newest version.